# Error: Multiple controller types were found that match the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Ao solicitar um serviço pela minha App, me dá esse erro:

> Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can
>   happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested
>   URL.\r\n\r\nThe request has found the following matching controller
>   types:
>   \r\nAutorizadorService.Controllers.NegarController\r\nAutorizadorService.Controllers.AtualizaController",

Mas pelo App eu tenho isso:

```
public async Task UpdateLiberacaoAsync(double id, string value, List<Liberacao> liber)
        {
            try
            {
                string url = $"http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/atualiza/{id}/{value}";
                var uri = new Uri(string.Format(url));
                var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(liber);
                var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;
                response = await client.PutAsync(uri, content);

                //if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                //{
                //    throw new Exception("Erro ao atualizar tabela de liberacao");
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string er = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

e no meu serviço(AtorizadorService) veja isso:
Controller

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    [RoutePrefix("api/Atualiza")]
    public class AtualizaController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        PedidoLiberacao liberacao = new PedidoLiberacao();

        [Route("{id}/{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Put")]
        public void PutItensLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            liberacao.AtualizaLiberacao(id, value);
        }
    }
```

e minha model service

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                        .ToList();

            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 1;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            });

            contexto.SaveChanges();

        }
```

a questão toda é que eu tenho outra chamada Negar que é da mesma forma passada, os parâmetros assim

```
[Route("{id}/{value}")]
        public void AtualizaNegarLiberacao(int id, string value)
        {
            var lista = contexto.Liberacoes
                        .Where(l => l.IdOrcamento == id)
                        .ToList();

            lista.ForEach(f =>
            {
                f.FlagLiberacao = 2;
                f.AutorizouReceberAtrazado = value;
            });

            contexto.SaveChanges();

        }
```

como configuro as rotas para cada serviço, ele pegar a rota certa.

Answer (score 1):

Prefixe uma das rotas (ou as duas) com um nome único.

Por exemplo:

```
[Route("Negar/{id}/{value}")]
public void AtualizaNegarLiberacao(int id, string value) { }
```

Comment: LINQ e a chamada fica: `dominio/api/controller/negar/id/value`?

Comment: @pnet Este método não é do mesmo controller (`AtualizaController`) do outro?

Comment: Não, são diferentes. Não sei porque o erro. Tenho AtualizaController e NegarController